# how to prove the following linear matrix inequality

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, linear-matrix-inequality

$K=\{1,2,\dots,m\}$

$A_1,\dots, A_m$ be any square matrices. $n\times n$ say.

If there exist positive definite symmetric matrices $P_1,\dots, P_m$, $(n\times n)$ say.

such that, $A_i^TP_jA_i-P_i<0\forall (i,j)\in K\times K$ then I need to prove that $\exists\epsilon\in (0,1)$ such that

$A_i^TP_jA_i<(1-\epsilon)^2P_i$ holds for $(i,j)\in K\times K$

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Here "$<$" means the difference of the two matrices is p.s.d?

Comment: Absolutely yes, my friend...........

Comment: Doesn't this follow automatically by the set of p.s.d. matrices being open in the set of symmetric matrices?  If $A\prec B$ there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $A\prec(1-\epsilon)B$, much as in the case where $A$ and $B$ were real numbers?

Comment: postive definite, not psd though...

Comment: I didn't understand your logic sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fixed $i,j$, consider the function $f:\mathbb R\to M_n(\mathbb R)$: $f(\epsilon)=(1-\epsilon)^2 P_i-A_i^T P_j A_i$.  This map is continuous, and since $f(0)$ is assumed to be symmetric positive definite, and the set of symmetric positive definite matrices is open in $M_n(\mathbb R)$, the set of $\epsilon$ such that $f(\epsilon)$ is symmetric positive definite is a neighborhood of $0$.  Call that neighborhood $N_{i,j}$.  The intersection of the $K\times K$ neighborhoods $N_{i,j}$ of  $0$ is another neighborhood of $0$.  The intersection $N\cap (0,1)$ is non-empty, and for all $\epsilon$ in it, all your matrix inequalities are satisfied.

Comment: @Markov I was confused by your (to my mind nonstandard) use of the word "positive definite matrix" to include non-symmetric matrices.  Yes, your wide-sense p.d. matrices are open in the set of matrices.

Comment: Thanks for your help though.